# User shell on aws dies in 20 minutes

Tags: shell, tmux, amazon-web-services, timeout

I use an AWS server and shells (`bash`) under my `tmux` sessions die after 20 minutes of inactivity.

I do `ssh -t myserver tmux new-session`, then `C-b d` to detach.

Then

```
$ while sleep 60; do
    date -u +'%F %T'
    ssh myserver tmux ls 2>/dev/null
  done
```

and in about 20 minutes the session disappears.

However, if I have two windows in `tmux` and start another process in one of them (`less` or `vi` or `sudo su -` or ...), then the second window (plain `bash`) disappears in 20 minutes while the first one (`vim` &c) lives on.

I have used AWS before (with `tmux` and `screen`), and this is the first time I see this behavior.

How do I avoid this?

PS. This is not related to `ssh` timeouts (`ServerAliveInterval`); I am not connected by `ssh` when the shell is killed.

PPS. I asked this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/798908/134648) and got nothing, I hope it will be more relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it wasn't necessarily related to AWS.

I looked in `/etc/profile` and found `export TMOUT=$((60*60))`. From the [bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> If set to a value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as the default timeout for the read builtin (see Bash Builtins). The select command (see Conditional Constructs) terminates if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is coming from a terminal.
>
> In an interactive shell, the value is interpreted as the number of seconds to wait for a line of input after issuing the primary prompt. Bash terminates after waiting for that number of seconds if a complete line of input does not arrive.

Adding `unset TMOUT` to `$USER/.profile` (or `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, etc.) fixed it.